# I fire a create table statement on hive catalog from trino, the query gets stuck

Tags: hadoop, trino, hive-metastore, ozone

We are using trino (391) and hive metastore (2.1.1) with apache ozone without HA. (1.2.1)
When I fire a create table statement on hive catalog from trino, the query gets stuck. The query neither shows progress nor ends.
What would be the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us if you can query the metastore from the command line, without going through trino?

Comment: yes @RobertRapplean